# Are @Bean and @Component annotations the same but for different targets in Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Am I correct, thinking that @Bean and @Component annotations are the same, but first is for classes and another is for methods?

In both cases container just creates appropriate beans, right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Not quite.** They belong to different concepts.

`@Component` is a stereotype annotation. A class annotated with this annotation will be auto detected during class path scanning. See also Spring reference documentation chapter 5.10. Other than that the `@Bean` annotation belongs to the Java configuration feature. Within a configuration class this annotation is used to mark methods that define beans.

Comment: A better answer than in the linked duplicate question. This answer here would still a bit better with easy examples :)